# Where to add . env file , GitHub private repo or cyclic.sh?

Tags: node.js, backend, telegram-bot, .env

I have nodejs backend files as private repo on GitHub , which I deployed to cyclic.sh ,

Project has .env file ,

So , where to keep .env ? On GitHub ( gitignore ) or on cyclic as variable?

Actually, .env has my bot token , which has Api telegram code , but telegram Bot not working,

I tried by deployed on vercel , set .env variable,same problem..

What I missed , how i get telegram Bot working?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should never include `.env` file in your GitHub repository, even if it's private. Environment variables should be set on the hosting platform you are using. You should refer to platform documentations for more information.

cyclic.sh : https://docs.cyclic.sh/concepts/env_vars

vercel : https://vercel.com/docs/projects/environment-variables